# executar function

Tags: php

Gostaria de executar as seguintes *functions*, `excel()` que gera o arquivo excel, e a função `pdf()`, esses arquivos são gerados dentro de uma pesquisa, porem não consigo executar através de botões, e como eles são gerados automaticamente, resolvi criar function para poderem ser executadas, mas não deu muito certo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<?php   

define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF('p', 'cm', 'A4');
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);


include "conexao.php";




$busca = $_POST['palavra'];// palavra que o usuario digitou

$busca_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carreteiro WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' or cidade like '%$busca%' or estado like '%$busca%' or bairro like '%$busca%' or rua like '%$busca%'")or die(mysql_error());//faz a busca com as palavras enviadas


if (empty($busca_query)) { 
    echo "Nenhum registro encontrado.";
}

// quando existir algo em '$busca_query' ele realizará o script abaixo.
while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($busca_query)) {

    echo "Nome : $dados[nome]<br />"; 
    echo "Cidade: $dados[cidade] <br />";
    echo "Estado: $dados[estado]<br />";
    echo "Rua: $dados[rua]<br />";
    echo "Bairro: $dados[bairro]<br />";
    echo "<hr>";

}



//inicio pdf /////////////////////////////////

function pdf(){

$exe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carreteiro WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' or cidade like '%$busca%' or estado like '%$busca%' or bairro like '%$busca%' or rua like '%$busca%'")or die(mysql_error());


while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($exe))
 {
    $pdf->Cell(3,1,$dados['nome'],1,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(4,1,$dados['cidade'],1,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(2,1,$dados['estado'],1,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(5,1,$dados['rua'],1,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(5,1,$dados['bairro'],1,0,'L');

 }
    ob_start ();
$pdf->Output();

}


?>

<form action="pdf()"><input type="submit" value="Gerar PDF" /></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isto realmente não funciona.

O problema, é que PHP é uma linguagem executada dentro do servidor, e o HTML, bem como Javascript, são "linguagens" do cliente. Portanto, nao é possível chamar métodos PHP diretamente do cliente.

O que você deve fazer é no `action` colocar o endereço do `script` que irá realizar a geração do relatório, e especificar o formato desejado. No `script` PHP da geração do relatório, você então decide e executa o método apropriado (para gerar Excel ou PDF).

Simplificadamente, seria algo como:

**index.php**

```
<form action="relatorio-pdf.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="palavra" />
    <input type="submit" value="Gerar PDF" />
</form>
```

**relatorio-pdf.php**

```
<?php
    // tentei adaptar seu código para tornar o exemplo mais concreto.
    define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf=new FPDF('p', 'cm', 'A4');
    $pdf->Open();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);

    include "conexao.php";

    $busca = $_POST['palavra'];// palavra que o usuario digitou
    $exe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carreteiro WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' or cidade like '%$busca%' or estado like '%$busca%' or bairro like '%$busca%' or rua like '%$busca%'")or die(mysql_error());

    while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($exe))
    {
        $pdf->Cell(3,1,$dados['nome'],1,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(4,1,$dados['cidade'],1,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(2,1,$dados['estado'],1,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(5,1,$dados['rua'],1,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(5,1,$dados['bairro'],1,0,'L');
    }
    ob_start ();
    $pdf->Output();
```

Repare que este código simplesmente gera o PDF. Gerar o HTML e o XLS podem ser códigos separados ou você pode modificar este exemplo para suportar tudo isto em um único código.

Espero ter ajudado a clarear um pouco suas idéias.

**Edição**

O PHP precisa de algum modo saber qual a palavra para realizar a busca. No exemplo que montei, segui o seu código que espera um parâmetro `POST` com o nome `palavra`.

O fluxo de uma aplicação normal é o seguinte:

1. Exibe uma página pedindo para o usuário digitar a palavra para a busca;
2. Exibe uam página com os resultados da busca, e botões para exportar os resultados em PDF (ou qualquer outro formato) desejado.

Vou exemplificar como você poderia construir isso:

O *item 1* seria construído no arquivo `busca.php`; a busca seria realizada e exibida no arquivo `resultado.php`; exportar para PDF no arquivo `exportar-pdf.php`.

Observação, vou mostrar apenas as partes interessantes do HTML.

*busca.php*

```
<form action="resultado.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="palavra" />
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
</form>
```

*resultado.php*

Este arquivo segue o que você mesmo desenvolveu, porém sem a parte do PDF:

```
<?php   
    define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');

    include "conexao.php";

    $busca = $_POST['palavra'];// palavra que o usuario digitou

    $busca_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carreteiro WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' or cidade like '%$busca%' or estado like '%$busca%' or bairro like '%$busca%' or rua like '%$busca%'")or die(mysql_error());//faz a busca com as palavras enviadas

    if (empty($busca_query)) { 
        echo "Nenhum registro encontrado.";
    }

    // quando existir algo em '$busca_query' ele realizará o script abaixo.
    while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($busca_query)) {
        echo "Nome : $dados[nome]<br />"; 
        echo "Cidade: $dados[cidade] <br />";
        echo "Estado: $dados[estado]<br />";
        echo "Rua: $dados[rua]<br />";
        echo "Bairro: $dados[bairro]<br />";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
?>
<form action="exportar-pdf.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="palavra" value="<?php echo $busca; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Gerar PDF" />
</form>
```

Repare que dentro do `form`, adicionei um campo oculto com o nome `palavra`, inicializado com a palavra de busca previamente digitada. Deste modo, podemos passar ela para o script que irá exportar os dados da busca em PDF.

*exporta-pdf.php*

```
<?php
    // tentei adaptar seu código para tornar o exemplo mais concreto.
    define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf=new FPDF('p', 'cm', 'A4');
    $pdf->Open();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);

    include "conexao.php";

    $busca = $_POST['palavra'];// palavra que o usuario digitou
    $exe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carreteiro WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' or cidade like '%$busca%' or estado like '%$busca%' or bairro like '%$busca%' or rua like '%$busca%'")or die(mysql_error());

    while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($exe))
    {
        $pdf->Cell(3,1,$dados['nome'],1,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(4,1,$dados['cidade'],1,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(2,1,$dados['estado'],1,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(5,1,$dados['rua'],1,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(5,1,$dados['bairro'],1,0,'L');
    }
    ob_start ();
    $pdf->Output();
```

Note que o código deste arquivo, é exatamente o código que coloquei anteriormente!

**Conclusão**

Deste modo, temos o fluxo completo da aplicação. Não verifiquei se suas queries estão corretas. Sem ter o DDL do banco, é complicado fazer isto, e aparentemente, não é este o problema.

A solução por AJAX postada em outra resposta, também é opção. Porém, recomendo que primeiro faça deste modo, que é mais simples por exigir apenas conhecimento em PHP. A solução por AJAX necessita de conhecimento em Javascript, e não exclui os conhecimentos de PHP, portanto melhor antes consolidar do modo mais simples, e então partir para a implementação mais complexa (e, neste caso, nem tão complexa assim e muito melhor!).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: amigo muito obrigado, funcionou.

porém ele permanece aparecendo o campo de pesquisa, como não entendo, tem como remover o campo aonde pesquiso?

`código` <input type="text" name="palavra" /> `código`

Comment: olhei novamente, e esta sendo gerado pdf de todos os dados do banco, não somente o da busca :/

Comment: Tem sim, é só remover o campo. Como disse, modifiquei seu código apenas para dar um ponto de partida. Vou adicionar mais informações à resposta.

Comment: obrigado pela atenção, consegui executar porem persiste no mesmo, ele não filtra a palavra e acaba puxando todos os dados do banco

Comment: Este é um outro problema, diferente da execução de uma chamada PHP. Recomendo que abra uma nova questão apenas para ele, e informe a estrutura da sua tabela, exemplo de dados, etc.

Comment: desde já agradeço a ajuda, muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

O php não funciona dessa forma, com o javascript você conseguiria fazer, mas com o php você precisa recarregar a página ou usar  [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Seu form tem que enviar um POST ou GET com a informação que o php precisa executar a função, exemplo:

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="comando" value="pdf" />
<input type="submit" value="Gerar PDF" />
</form>
```

Já no php vc faria o seguinte:

```
<?php
$comando = $_GET["comando"];

if ($comando == "pdf") {
   pdf(); // chama a função aqui
}

?>
```